# Ionic Visual Studio Components don't load

Tags: css, visual-studio, ionic-framework

I have got a blank Ionic starter app in Visual Studio.
Now I am trying to use the components from the Ionic Api documentation.

The button documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/button/Button/

It says to use the following code for a full button:

```
<button ion-button full>Full Button</button>
```

And this for a stack-input:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Stacked Label</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Email Input"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Unfortunately it doesn' render correctly. This is the result from the emulator:
[image]

Comment: what ionic version are you using? you can check this with the command "ionic -v" from your cli

Comment: It is version 3.4.0

Comment: are you getting the same error while serving it through browser?

Comment: Let me try @Gowtham

Comment: Doesn't work either

Comment: seems weird! can you post your html code completely to see whats wrong

Comment: Yes sure, will update in a minute. Do you have Visual Studio? It is the pre installed blank starter app with just the code added from above.

Comment: I have visual studio code. try starting a new app to see if the components work as documented

Comment: I tried everything but it isn't displayed properly... @Gowtham